# Websocket. Приходят не все сообщения

Tags: node.js, websocket

Я пытаюсь прослушивать вебсокет с другого сайта. Вебсокет отправляет 2 типа сообщения `type:ka` и `type:data`, я получаю сообщения `type:ka`, а сообщения `type:data` не приходят (сообщения этого типа мгновенно 2 штуки отправляется, возможно проблема в этом?)

Мой код

```
const ws = new WebSocket(soketurl, 'graphql-ws');

ws.on('open', () => console.log('open'));
ws.on('close', (err) => console.log('close', err));
ws.on('error', (err) => console.log('error', err));
ws.on('upgrade', () => console.log('upgrade'));
ws.on('ping', () => console.log('ping'));
ws.on('message', (messages) => {
    const chank = messages;
    console.log(JSON.parse(chank));
});
```

Comment: Что за type:ka и type:data ? Почему решили что не приходят? Может не отправляются? Покажите код, как отправляете сообщение с разными типами

Comment: это не мой вебсокет, я пытаюсь прослушивать вебсокет с другого сайта

Comment: Нельзя принять то, чего нет ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Судя по предоставленному коду, что пришло, то и отображается. Отдлеьно можете посмотреть в консоли разработчика - сеть, что там к вам по сокету летит

Comment: @SwaD вот какие сообщения отправляются вебсокетом на сайте https://prnt.sc/htrQRLy8p7T- , а вот то, что я получаю https://prnt.sc/KG8adKNKLJ8N  , то есть я не получаю сообщения `type:data`

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin как я уже написал, вебсокет сторонний, не мой. Выше скинул скрины из девконсоли, что должно быть, и что  получаю я

Comment: Может для сообщения type:ka надо с начало ответ отправить? Попробуй на состояния websocket поглядеть после открытия, сразу закрывается после отправки сообщения

Comment: У меня скрины не открываются

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin хм можешь подсказать как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @SwaD ссылки со скринами рабочие, проверил повторно, может попробуй инкогнито?

Comment: Для  type:data может надо подписаться? У тебя первый скрин с самого открытия websocket показывает? Если у сайта нет обратного ответа по каналу websocket, посмотри на адресную строку

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin в адресной строке параметров никаких нет, но в начале вижу, что есть 4 отправки https://prnt.sc/rRbRBXcSvA8Z , возможно поэтому я не получаю `data` но я не пойму как мне сделать отправки 
А вот сами данные сокета с сайта https://prnt.sc/htO_w7qy480W

Comment: На скрине вижу что приходящие type:data с id (id :1,id :2,id :3 b id :4) и на них запрос. После открытии сокета попробуй отправь те же формы `ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('Connection opened');
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ ... }));
};`

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin `ws.onopen = function() {   console.log('Connection opened');   ws.send(JSON.stringify({ ... })); };` если так писать ошибку получаю, сделал таким образом

`ws.on('send', () => {
    JSON.stringify({"type":"connection_init","payload":{}})
});`
добавил 5 отправок сообщений как на сайте, но `data` так и не приходит

Comment: Ссылку этого сайта можно?

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin https://polkastats.io/transfers